# SQLite output from query into Python script

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have this Python script:

```
s = stdscr.getstr(0,0, 20) #input length last number
            c = db.execute("""SELECT "debit" FROM "members" WHERE "barcode" = '%s' LIMIT 1""" % (s,))
            for row in c:
                    print row

                    if row == '(0,)':
                            #display cross
                            print 'Tick'
                    else:
                            #display tick
                            print 'Cross'
```

Where it is asking for a barcode input, and matching the debit field in the database.

The "print row" command returns "(0,)" but when I try to match it, I always get "Cross" as the output, which is not the intended result. Is there a semantic I'm obviously not observing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `row` is a tuple, and `'(0,)'` is its string representation. Your are comparing a variable with its string representation, which cannot work.

You need to compare it to the tuple value

```
if row == (0,):
```

Simply remove the quote marks.

Alternatively, you can write

```
if row[0] == 0:
```

which will avoid the creation of a tuple just for the comparison. As noted by @CL., `row` will never be an empty tuple so extracting `row[0]` is safe.

Comment: Wouldn't `row[0] == 0` be better?

Comment: @CL. The disadvantage I see is that you need then to catch `IndexError: tuple index out of range` then. But maybe `execute` will never return an empty tuple in this case. Am I missing something? Do you see a clear advantage to your approach?

Comment: The value might be NULL, but it will always be there.